# No Comments on Facebook Comment Moderation Tool

Tags: facebook, comments

In this page:
http://daytona.bg/model/damska-tunika-751-sreb-tsip_2702/

I have the following code inserted for facebook comments:

```
<head>
    <meta property="fb:admins" content="1816718833"/>
    <meta property="fb:app_id" content="443454829050436"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="fb-comments" data-href="/model/damska-tunika-751-sreb-tsip_2702/" data-num-posts="5" data-width="960"></div>
</body>
```

But on moderation tool page I don't see any comments:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/comments?id=443454829050436&view=queue

BTW, everything worked before I changed my application ID (I deleted my old app by mistake).

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the full URL on your "data-href". Something like:

```
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://www.exemple.com/model/damska-tunika-751-sreb-tsip_2702/">
```